# surefire vs failsafe : proguard issue

Tags: integration-testing, proguard, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I just start working with an existing application where tests are mixed up (unit tests and integration tests) under src/test and i need to sort things out and put right tests at right place.

All are running fine with surefire right now but when trying to move integration test to failsafe, i can't figure out why it is not working.
I am getting this error while performing a select during a bean creation : `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`
It seems a table is missing in the database.

I can see that whith surefire, there is a step which uses hibernate to clear database and recreate it before running the tests but i can't see it with failsafe.
I don't know where to look up for this step and how to activate it with failsafe.

I am not very familiar with the environment but i know there is :

- maven 3.2.5
- maven-surefire-plugin 2.19.1
- maven-failsafe-plugin 2.19.1
- spring framework 4.0.0

Thanks for any suggestion for where to look.
Is there any difference between surefire and failsafe that need to be configured differently from one to another to run the exact same test?

### The problem

Trying to create an MCVE, i figured out that the issue is not annotations but **proguard-maven-plugin**.
The problem can be reproduced with an sql database and a simple maven project with these files :

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>myArtifactId</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>MCVE</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>               
    </dependencies>     

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <dependencies> 
                    <dependency> 
                        <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                        <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                        <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>proguard</goal></goals>
                        </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <proguardInclude>${basedir}/obfuscation.config.debug</proguardInclude>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>           
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>   
                <configuration>
                   <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>                
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-tests</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*It.java</include>
                            </includes>         
                        </configuration>                        
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>                     
                            <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*It.java</include>
                            </includes>                         
                        </configuration>                        
                    </execution>
                </executions>               
              </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>  

</project>
```

**User.java**

```
package myPackage;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private String username;

    public User() {}

    public final String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public final void setUsername(final String pUsername) {
        username = pUsername;
    }

}
```

**UserIt.java**

```
package myPackage;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests;

@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:/test.xml"})
public class UserIt extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests implements ApplicationContextAware {

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        System.out.println("MyTestIsOK");
    }

}
```

**obfuscation.config.debug**

```
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate
-dontpreverify
-ignorewarnings
-keep class **
```

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- xmlns:websocket="http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket" -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd"
    >

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>myUser</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>myPwd</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>myPackage</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Running clean integration-test with surefire will create the *user* table before running the test but not with failsafe.

Comment: The have different phase in the lifecyle build. Take a look at the different goal and phase https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html I'd be glad to help if you post concrete stuff but as for now I can't find a solution there is not enough information in this question

Comment: are the surefire and failsafe configuration in the same pom? The surefire execution causes hibernate to update the database - the failsafe plugin execution does not do that, so it seems the spring configuration for hibernate is different? Are the configuration files the same? And the classpath? Can you try to remove the argLine for once? The jacoco docs states to not set the argLine that way: http://eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html

Comment: I updated my answer to respond to your edits 1-3. Don't know if you get a notification about it, I did not get a notification about your edits...

Comment: No i didn't receive any notification, i just checked everyday. I'll be away for a couple of weeks so i'll try to create an MCVE by mid april. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say something specific without having more information (e.g. relevant parts from `pom.xml`). Here are some general pointers to give some background though:

## Maven build lifecycle

A normal Maven build [runs through several phases](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference). The relevant phases (with simplified descriptions) for this discussion are:

- …
- `test`: runs unit tests
- …
- (`package`: build a `jar` or `war` file)
- `pre-integration-test`: prepares the environment for integration tests
- `integration-test`: runs integration tests
- `post-integration-test`: shuts down the integration test environment
- `verify`: checks the result from the integration test
- …

So Maven is designed to run integration tests in a special environment. An example would be that a Tomcat is set up and started and the projects `war` file (that was built in the `package` phase) is deployed on it in the `pre-integration-test` phase. Than the integration tests are run in the `integration-test` phase. In the `post-integration-test` phase the Tomcat is shut down. The test results are collected in the `verify` phase.

## `maven-surefire-plugin` vs `maven-failsafe-plugin`

Both plugins belong to the [Maven Surefire project](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/).

The [`maven-surefire-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) runs unit tests and binds to the `test` phase by default.

The [`maven-failsafe-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) runs integration tests and binds to the `integration-test` and `verify` phases by default.

The reason that there are those two different plugins is, that the `maven-failsafe-plugin` does not fail the build immediately so the `post-integration-test` phase will run in any case. Only the `verify` phase fails the build on test failures.

## Your problem

In response to your edits 1-3: Are you sure the integration tests include `ContextManagerTest`? It sounds like the `maven-failsafe-plugin` does not know about this test class and thus does not execute its `@Before` method and thus does not initialize the Spring context and thus does not recreate the database using Hibernate.

Try to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by removing all irrelevant classes and configurations, only keeping e.g. one unit test, one integration test, the `ContextManagerTest` (each of which do something stupid like a `System.out.println(…)`) and the `pom.xml`.

Comment: I have added the MCVE.

Comment: @baadshah: Thanks, I'll have a look during the next week, if not someone else answers in the meantime…

Comment: @baadshah: I can reproduce your problem using the MCVE, thanks! Your code looks good to me, I've no idea what could be wrong with it causing this behavior. I'm afraid more intensive debugging is required to find the root of your problem, but I don't have enough time to do it… :-(

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll wait for other answers then.